# Telling if a member's type is a specialization of some template

Tags: c++, templates

Consider the following:

```
template <typename type> class __member__
{
  // Something happening here, but nobody cares.
};
```

Now, at some point in my code, I get an expression that involves, say, `myobject.mymember`. I would like to find out if `mymember`'s type is a specialization of `__member__`.

Of course, I thought about doing something like:

```
template <typename type> class is_member;

template <typename type> class is_member <__member__ <type>>
{
  static constexpr bool value = true;
}

template <typename type> class is_member
{
  static constexpr bool value = false;
}
```

And go with a `decltype`:

```
std :: cout << is_member <decltype(myobject.mymember)> :: value << std :: endl;
```

But this isn't obvious. Say, for example, that the expression `myobject.mymember` lies in a `myobject.mymember();` line. Either `mymember` is a member exposing a `()` operator, or `mymember` is a function, possibly overloaded.

So I am a bit stuck. Is there any better way to get this done? I only have `myobject.mymember`, and no further information.

Comment: Look at various [trait templates](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types) that are available, like `std::is_function`, `std::is_class`, `std::is_member_object_pointer`, `std::is_member_function_pointer`, etc

Comment: What exactly is your problem with `is_member`? That the `decltype` won't work if `mymember` is a member function?